# PHP logout specific redirect when in certain directory

Tags: php, redirect, logout

When a user is logged into the site I'm working on, a "Logout" link appears, that calls this code:

```
<?php    
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
} else {
  header('Location: /index.php');  
} 
exit;  
?>
```

This works well for most of the site but I have a special directory ('archives-logged-in') where, if they log out, I want them to return to the index.php page at the site root. I've tried to see if the user is in the designated directory and if so, redirect accordingly:

```
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
$isArchives = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'archives-logged-in');
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (!$isArchives)) {
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
} else {
  header('Location: /index.php');  
} 
exit;  
?>
```

However, it doesn't work. The log out occurs (I have some nav items only visible to the logged in members), but the user stays on the same page. How can I redirect them to the home page if they are in my 'archives-logged-in' directory?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: Well, we can start with `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (!$isArchives))` should be `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && ($isArchives !== false))`.

Comment: Yup - that's it. Basic syntax snafu. Put that into a answer so I can credit you. Thanks!